# PHP SQL / You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I am having some serious difficulty trying to insert a user variable into a database.
I keep getting the error **You have an error in your SQL syntax**. I have searched the form for a few days and tried different solutions but to no avail.I tried using `'$var'` , `'".$var."'` , `"$var"` but no luck. 
If i use $var with no quotes i get the error **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

A code snippet and data tables are below.

```
$con= mysqli_connect("oni", "mul", "kjnbiunvtr","mul"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$drugName=$_POST['drugName']; 
$drugName=mysql_real_escape_string($drugName);

$treats=$_POST['treats'];
$treats=mysql_real_escape_string($treats);

$effects=$_POST['effects']; 
$effects =mysql_real_escape_string($effects);

$sideEffect=$_POST['SideEffects']; 
$sideEffect= mysql_real_escape_string($sideEffect);

$sideEffect2=$_POST['SideEffects2']; 
$sideEffect2=mysql_real_escape_string($sideEffect2);

$sideEffect3=$_POST['SideEffects3']; 
$sideEffect3= mysql_real_escape_string($sideEffect3);

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Drug(drug) VALUES('$drugName')");

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Drug insertion successful : ";
    echo "\r\n";
}
else
{
    echo "Error 1 :  " . mysqli_error($con);
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Tables:

```
$sql1="CREATE TABLE Drug
    (Id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id),
        drug VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";


$sql2="CREATE TABLE DrugSideEffect
    ( Id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        D_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
        SE_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id),
        FOREIGN KEY (SE_Id) REFERENCES SideEffect(Id),
        FOREIGN KEY (D_Id) REFERENCES Drug(Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";


$sql3="CREATE TABLE Treatment
    (Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        T_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
        Descr VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id),
        FOREIGN KEY (T_Id) REFERENCES Drug(Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";


$sql4="CREATE TABLE Effects
    (Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        E_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
        Descr VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id),
        FOREIGN KEY (E_Id) REFERENCES Drug(Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";


$sql5="CREATE TABLE SideEffect
    (Id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id),
        Descr VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
    )ENGINE=INNODB";
```

Comment: What is the bit of SQL that is failing?

Comment: Your first query is wide open to SQL injection. Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Use mysqli escape string you are mixing the two.And show the error message.

Comment: Why not to leave this job for someone who have a clue? There are SO MANY flaws, from database design to syntax issues, that no answer can fix them all.

Comment: Sidenote: => You're mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MySQL version is >= 5.5 and the `mysql_real_escape_string` function is deprecated. You can try to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` method like the following example.

```
$con= mysqli_connect("oni", "mul", "kjnbiunvtr","mul"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$drugName=$_POST['drugName']; 
$drugName=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $drugName);

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Drug(drug) VALUES('$drugName')");

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Drug insertion successful : ";
    echo "\r\n";
}
else
{
    echo "Error 1 :  " . mysqli_error($con);
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
     $sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Drug (drug) VALUES ('".$drugName."')");
```

EDIT:

your problem is with creating tables.

your tables are not well ordered, you should create table `SideEffect` before `DrugSideEffect`.

try this ordering:

```
$sql1="CREATE TABLE Drug
(Id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    drug VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;";
 $sql5="CREATE TABLE SideEffect
(Id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    Descr VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB";

$sql2="CREATE TABLE DrugSideEffect
( Id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    D_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
    SE_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (SE_Id) REFERENCES SideEffect(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (D_Id) REFERENCES Drug(Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;";


$sql3="CREATE TABLE Treatment
(Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    T_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
    Descr VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (T_Id) REFERENCES Drug(Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;";


$sql4="CREATE TABLE Effects
(Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    E_Id int (11) NOT NULL,
    Descr VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (E_Id) REFERENCES Drug(Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;";
```

Comment: this is one of the trials described in the question

Answer (score -1):

`$con= mysqli_connect("oni", "mul", "kjnbiunvtr","mul");`

`if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}`

`$drugName=$_POST['drugName'];`

`$drugName=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $drugName);`

`$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Drug(drug) VALUES('$drugName')");`

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
`{
    echo "Drug insertion successful : ";
    echo "\r\n";
}`
`else`
`{
    echo "Error 1 :  " . mysqli_error($con);
    echo "\r\n";
}`